# How to get PrivateKey from keystore.pkcs12 file

Tags: java, encryption, keystore, private-key, pkcs#12

I am trying to get privateKey from keystore file,

```
    keyStore.load(KeyStoreinputStream, "keystorepass".toCharArray());

PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, new char[0]);
```

new char[0] --> I have not given password for private key at the time of generation.

**getting below exception:**

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:792)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:355)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new char[0]` isn't correct. If there is no key password, use `null.`